# " Movesense ECG sample keeps stopping" and error “couldn't find "libmds.so"

Tags: android, loadlibrary, movesense

I'm using Android Studio version 3.3 on Windows 10 (64 bit). Here are the characteristics of virtual devices on which the error occurred:

- Nexus 5X API 28, Android 9.0, CPU/ABI: x86
- Nexus 5X API 28, Android 9.0, CPU/ABI: x86_64
- Nexus 5 API 24, Android 7.0, CPU/ABI: x86
- Pixel API 27, Android 8.1, CPU/ABI: x86

The Movesense mobile library version: 1.28.1.

I downloaded the folder suunto-movesense-mobile-lib-e78baa174a4a from the Movesense website (https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/downloads/) and I tried to run the various samples for Android. The problem I'm going to show is documented for ECGSample but it has also occurred for the other three.
The application is built correctly but when I run the application on the virtual device I have the following error:

Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session:

```
INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113.
It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.
```

(Changing Android device and API version, the same error occurred). I solved this problem adding this to my Module's build.gradle script Inside Android{} block:

```
 splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

After doing this, the application was launched on the virtual device but unfortunately crashes immediately. The application starts correctly but closes immediately with the following message:

```
" Movesense ECG sample keeps stopping".
```

By checking the Logcat I have the following errors:

```
2019-02-08 12:03:28.641 4770-4770/com.movesense.samples.ecgsampleE/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.movesense.samples.ecgsample,PID: 4770
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:No implementation found for void com.movesense.mds.SDSInternalWrapper.sdsSetDelegate(java.lang.Object)(tried Java_com_movesense_mds_SDSInternalWrapper_sdsSetDelegate and Java_com_movesense_mds_SDSInternalWrapper_sdsSetDelegate__Ljava_lang_Object_2)
at com.movesense.mds.SDSInternalWrapper.sdsSetDelegate(NativeMethod)
at com.movesense.mds.SDSInternalWrapper.setDelegate(SDSInternalWrapper.java:167)
at com.movesense.mds.internal.operation.MdsOperationHandler.<init>(MdsOperationHandler.java:87)
at com.movesense.mds.Mds$Builder.build(Mds.java:357)
at com.movesense.samples.ecgsample.MainActivity.initMds(MainActivity.java:85)
at com.movesense.samples.ecgsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(NativeMethod)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

To catch the real problem, we debug the program, it gets an error and the error is “couldn't find "libmds.so".
 Details:

```
System.loadLibrary(mds) FAILED! Error: sds: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.movesense.samples.ecgsample-gmciklKIfxkuippl92JJAQ==/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmds.so"
```

The code that error occurred.

```
private native void sdsSetDelegate(Object var1);

static {
    try {
        Log.d("SDSInternalWrapper", "Start load library call [mds]");
        System.loadLibrary("mds"); (Error occurred)
        Log.d("SDSInternalWrapper", "Finished load library call [mds]");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var2) {
        String error = String.format("System.loadLibrary(mds) FAILED! Error: sds: %s", var2);
        Log.e("SDSInternalWrapper", error);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current MDS does not have x86 or x64 support, that is why you are getting the UnsatisfiedLinkError. Therefore it cannot be used with Android simulator for now, only debugging on device.

*Full Disclaimer: I work for the Movesense team*

Answer (score 0):

From the build.gradle in the showcase app the mdslib-.aar library should be located in the Movesense folder located at "../Movesense/" relative to the project or if you are trying the other examples it should be located at "../../../Movesense/" have you placed it there?

If not try keeping the folder structure as it is here https://bitbucket.org/suunto/movesense-mobile-lib/src/master/android/

```
|_Movesense/ 
| |_libmds-<version>.aar
|  
|_Showcasapp/
| |_gradle/
| |_src/
| |
| 
|_Samples/
```